# Optimal Duck Game Moves

Tags: code-golf, game

### How to play the duck game

**This is a 2-player game.**

First, we start with a line of blue rubber ducks (represented here as circles):

> 

Now, in each turn, the current player can turn either one blue duck or two adjacent blue ducks red.

So, a valid move would be indexes 2 and 3 (0-indexed):

> 

Then, the other player could choose index 0:

> 

And so on. The last player to move loses.

#### Example game

Starting with 7 blue ducks:

> Initial board

> Player 1 chooses **3,4**

> Player 2 chooses **0**

> Player 1 chooses **6**

> Player 2 chooses **1,2**

> Player 1 chooses **5**

Player 1 was the last one to move, so Player 2 wins.

---

### Challenge

The duck game can be solved. Your challenge today is to accept a board state and output one of the moves which will guarantee a win for the current player.

For example, with the board state , choosing either index 0 or index 2 will guarantee a win for the current player (feel free to try it).

### Input/Output

- You should take in a list/array/etc. containing two distinct values representing blue and red ducks. 
  For example,  could be `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]`.
- You should output one or two integers representing the ducks which should be taken in the next move. 
  For example, the input  could have output `[0]` or `[2]`.

### Clarifications

- The input board state will always have at least one move which guarantees a win for the current player.
- You may output **any** of the moves which guarantee a win.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in bytes wins.

### Test cases

These test cases use 1 for blue ducks and 0 for red ducks. The output side contains all possible outputs.

```python
Input  ->  Output
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]  ->  [0], [2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  ->  [1], [3], [5]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]  ->  [0,1], [3,4], [5,6]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]  ->  [0]
[1, 1, 1]  ->  [0,1], [1,2]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]  ->  [3], [4]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25928/114446)

Comment: This game is called ([misère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mis%C3%A8re#Mis%C3%A8re_game)) [Kayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayles). A solution was first published in W.L. Silbert, J.H. Conway, “[Mathematical Kayles](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01253778)”, _Int J Game Theory_ 20, 237–246 (1992).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg, I found the paper interesting but difficult.  Re: the appearance of the phano plane -- is there some deeper connection to projective geometry, or was that merely a convenient visual aid?  Also, if I understood correctly, the normal version game is almost trivial to solve and all of that analysis was to handle the misere version?  Is that correct?

Comment: I was disappointed to find that this question has nothing to do with https://store.steampowered.com/app/312530/Duck_Game/ lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>71</s> 52 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕⍘⮌Ｓ²⊞υ⎇ιΦ⁺Ｅθ⟦λ⟧Ｅθ⟦λ⊕λ⟧∧⁼ΣＸ²κ＆ΣＸ²κι¬§υ⁻ιΣＸ²κ⟦⟦⟧⟧Ｉ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PawIxEMXv/RTB0wRScPXoaZVaPFgW7U08hN2pGTabaP4o/fRpUq210AdDwptM3m9aJV1rpU6p9p4OBubS4zY4MgfY4BmdR1iZYww3j3PBJrkUnz010SuIgo3z/cM6Boqz77M2n9Do6GEtj3ASrLEXdDARTJfxm/lOA3qY/u2W/qtDGbLzcopSe@gFm1O4kMfadECC9eXRwkYTSviaTA662lnsB4oKYEYOsJA@wJJ0@fORatfvf2l2OWZlWocDmoAd9Hz/yPJmA9yTlmS6WusyNqpG/B8cJdg2DnDfjPhVs5Sqalxlpeez/gI) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a string of `0`s and `1`s representing red and blue ducks respectively and outputs a double-spaced list of winning `0`-indexed duck moves. Explanation: Uses dynamic programming to find winning moves.

```
Ｆ⊕⍘⮌Ｓ²
```

Loop over numeric positions indices from `0` to the input as a position index, some of which will be unreachable from the input position.

```
⊞υ⎇ιΦ⁺Ｅθ⟦λ⟧Ｅθ⟦λ⊕λ⟧∧⁼ΣＸ²κ＆ΣＸ²κι¬§υ⁻ιΣＸ²κ⟦⟦⟧⟧
```

Find all legal moves that result in forced losses from this position, but special case a list of an empty list for position index `0` which should really be a loss for the player to move (this would save `6` bytes).

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output all winning moves from the input position.

Comment: "but special case a list of an empty list for position index 0 which should really be a loss for the player to move" I think an empty list would be a loss for the player to move, and hence invalid input -- or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Jonah An empty list means that it's a loss for the player to move, as they have no winning moves, which is why I have to make it a list of an empty list, so that the player who moves to that position loses. This is because this version of the game is being played as a misère game. In a normal game, the empty position is a loss for the player to move, which avoids this special case.

Answer (score 4):

## Python3, 333 bytes:

```py
def M(l):
 for i,a in enumerate(l):
  if a:
   yield[i]
   if i<len(l)-1and l[i+1]:yield[i,i+1]
def K(l):
 for m in M(l):
  L=l[:]
  for i in m:L[i]=0
  yield L,m
def P(l,p=1):
 F=1
 for L,_ in K(l):
  if any(L):
   if p in(u:=[*P(L,not p)]):yield from u;F=0
 if F:yield not p
f=lambda l:[m for L,m in K(l)if any(L)and not any(P(L))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Ba8QgEIXv@RVz1K4Lhl6Krddc1sLeJRRLlApqJCSH/PrUSdLu0t0tDMSZ9@Z9kzyPX316fsnDsnTWwTsJVFTg@gE8M@AT2DRFO5jRbgp4Bwa/MHsbOu1bfJehfws2Fc@xNqmDoP2hbsXuYdhUmH@65EdM33mgZNACo1YyKlGoEi55tZNAsbhGnElgWda41sh6y1LsA3dOVzemmai1wS4XlUxC6qczUSz1I2Ta0u08cEMfYXptkFW8zT5eXZWTwcTPzkAQOu6s@MP65eAvox@7QqC0XfLg00gc0TWDrfha@G4prW71S93R@X86v0I8yr@zw/9cdrNWBss3)

Comment: You can remove `0<=` in the check of function `M`, since `i` is always \$\geq0\$.

Comment: Also, `L=eval(str(l))` can be `L=l.copy()`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `L=l.copy()` can be `L=l[:]`

Comment: Do you need the `enumerate`? using `l[i]` instead of `a` might be a bit shorter
edit: nvm I forgot about the length of `range(len(i))`

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 78 bytes

-5 bytes from Arnauld

```javascript
f=x=>x.some(r=(v,i,[...e])=>v?r=f(e,e[i]=0)?f(e,e[i-1]=0)?0:[i-1,i]:[i]:0)?r:r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P822wtauQq84PzdVo8hWo0wnUydaT08vNVbT1q7Mvsg2TSNVJzU6M9bWQNMeytY1BPMMrEBMncxYIB1rBRQosir6X1CUmVeikaYRbaijAEEGYARix2pqcmHKIxAWeQN88gZIVuAyH4seAzSXAZX8BwA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 81 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,e)=>x.some((v,i)=>r=v?f(e=[...x],e[i]=0)?f(e,e[i-1]=0)?0:[i-1,i]:[i]:0)?r:!e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P81Wo0InVdPWrkKvOD83VUOjTCcTyCuyLbNP00i1jdbT06uI1UmNzoy1NdAECYHYuoZgnoEViKmTGQukY62AAkVWiqn/C4oy80o00jSiDXUUIMgAjEDsWE1NLkx5BMIib4BP3gDJClzmY9FjgOYyFCUQMQNs2oBi/wE)

returns `false` if impossible, returns `true` if win immediately because of endgame.

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P822wtauQq84PzdVo8hWo0wnUydaT08vNVbT1q7Mvsg2TSNVJzU6M9bWQNMeytY1BPMMrEBMncxYIB1rBRQosir6X1CUmVeikaYRbaijAEEGYARix2pqcmHKIxAWeQN88gZIVuAyH4seAzSXAZX8BwA), I think (based on your initial version).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 178 bytes

```haskell
z f=zipWith f[0..]
n=Nothing
f x|and x=Just[]
f x|h:_<-filter(\j->all(\k->k<length x&&not(x!!k))j&&n==f((\k->z(\i y->y||elem i k)x)j))$concat$z(\i _->[[i],[i,i+1]])x=Just h
f x=n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVKxTsMwEBVrvuIqVZUtnCotBaGqycYAAyuDa7VRiRs3jlM1Lkqr_AlLF8TO35SvwXaAliCdfGf7vbt3Z7--p3GZJVIeDm9bzf3b48ceeLgX6yehU-A06PeZp8LHQqdCLT0OVR2rZ6jCh22pKXMH6Xg28bmQOtmg6cqPYinRNPOjbCITtTRpql5PFRpVnU6G8cpswpAjB9mjqYCdH-3qOpFJDgIyXOEVxt1FoRax7jrAzI8oFYxQQcTlgDHclIfUlg9Vo_zz4kUnpV7EZVLCeAwU0XulGQHqPMPMO92HQD0ARAcEGguc2dgwDCWwxKFhkb-4kzU46-iVXa5b4OA_OCANnIwcgdycU4IzKec6WhJcQ9-JBmTYyhC0-nFoJ2_kJuDlsVCm-_VGKA0UOKA8XgMyzwN90MWd2uYYBIa5fY452Es36qKEGpAgJsAw8eF3lMxrxv_zgb4A)